# Selenium WebDriver + Firefox which version works fine?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on writing an automation script to test a website login. Through Firefox IDE, I have written TestCase steps, it is executing fine. I exported the test case as java code compatible with jUnit 4.

When i try to run the java code via Eclipse (with firefox browser), either it opens Mozilla homepage or blank page or proxy issue (if my machine is connected to company LAN).

I am using Selenium 2.44 and Firefox version 44.. 
Also i read in some websites saying about compatible version of firefox with selenium web driver. I am confused a lot regarding this.

Please let me know which version of Selenium Web driver, Firefox & Java is preferred..!!!

Adding my java code below

```
public class Firefox {
private WebDriver driver;
private String PROXY = "proxy address:port";
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
// Code for setting up Firefox proxy
Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
.setFtpProxy(PROXY)
.setSslProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
baseUrl = "url";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
public void testFirefox() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl);
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
try { 
if ("".equals(driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).getText())) break; 
}
catch (Exception e) {}
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("user name");
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: Show your code, do you use a proxy-server in your company LAN?

Comment: 'Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
   proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyadrs)
        .setFtpProxy(proxyadrs)
        .setSslProxy(proxyadrs);
   DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);'

Comment: this is the code i am using.. but this never change the firefox proxy details. firefox always point to system settings..

Comment: I see changelog of Selenium 2.44 says `* Updating Native events to support Firefox 24, 31, 32 and 33`, so probably you should use the latest version of Selenium

Comment: The latest version of Firefox that mentioned in the changelog of Selenium 2.51 is 39. So try Selenium 2.51 and Firefox v. 39

Comment: @Dmitry P. should i degrade firefox from 44 to 39?

Comment: yes, try if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest stable compatible configuration which i've found and I am using it is selenium Webdriver 2.48.2 and Firefox 41.0.2

Comment: Now i have a new issue setting up the proxy for firefox..Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
   proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
   .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
   .setSslProxy(PROXY)
   .setSocksProxy(PROXY);

Comment: This fills up the proxy details in firefox but still i am unable to access internet through firefox.. I need the option "use this proxy server for all protocols" to be checked automatically.. Is ther any option to do so?

Comment: Does this not works for you..proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl(proxyAutoconfigUrl)

Comment: this code selects the 'Automatic Proxy Configuration URL' options with the provided proxy value. But i wants to select 'Manual Proxy Configuration' option with the check box "use this proxy server for all protocols" selected.. Please help.. i tried so many options. but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Download Firefox ESR from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/

Its stable version browser of Firefox compatible with Webdriver 2.48.2.
Selenium WebDriver 2.48.2 will not work with FF 44.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Firefox always works with the latest version of Selenium (2.x versions) for all non-native events, such as JavascriptExecutor events, but there are some native events (such as driver.navigate.to()  and driver.click()  that won't work except with the last known native supported version of Firefox, which was [31.6.0 ESR](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/31.6.0esr/).   It's possible that later versions of ESR will work, but I have not read that anywhere.